# How to add a condition to check caseId has value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
if (obj.fieldId === 'CASE_ACTION' && this.caseDetails && this.caseDetails.caseId) {
        this.actionAlertCase();
        return;
      }
```

Want to add a condition to check caseId has value

Comment: If you check with **if (this.caseDetails.caseId)** will return true if the value is diferent of null and diferent of undefined and diferent of zero (for number types). This is what I understood you asking, if not please provide more details.

Comment: You're already checking if `this.caseDetails.caseId` has a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20truthy%20value,type%20coercion%20in%20Boolean%20contexts.)

Comment: Hi Zsolt and Alexandre, I think '&& this.caseDetails.caseId' is already check if 'caseId' has value (if it has value, then action alert will show up), but since it's still asking "add a condition to check caseId has value", should I add something like !=== null" to satisfy the condition? Thanks.

Comment: In this case you dont need to check if caseId is null, the truthy value commented by @ZsoltMeszaros already check for null and undefined